# Type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

> Type '(event: FormEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'.

In my parent component I'm just passing in a function which handles onChange to the child:

```
<SearchInput handleSearchTyping={this.handleSearchTyping}/>
```

---

```
@bind
handleSearchTyping(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const { value: searchText } = target;

  const search = (text: string) => {
    const { searchList } = this.state;
    const searchedCoins = findAsset(text, searchList);
    this.setState({ searchList: searchedCoins });
  };

  const clearSearch = () => {
    this.setState({ searchList: this.state.saved });
  };

  const handleUpdate = (num: number) => (num > 1 ? search(searchText) : clearSearch());

  return handleUpdate(searchText.length);
}
```

---

The child: SearchInput:

```
import React from 'react'

export const SearchInput = (props: { handleSearchTyping(): void }) =>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" onChange={props.handleSearchTyping} />;
```

[image]

Also tried:

```
interface IProps {
  handleSearchTyping(): void;
}

export const SearchInput = (props: IProps) =>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" onChange={props.handleSearchTyping} />;
```

What is the correct type to past into the props of `SearchInput`?

Comment: Try <SearchInput handleSearchTyping={() => this.handleSearchTyping}/>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah just fixed it:

```
import React from 'react'

interface IProps {
  handleSearchTyping(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void;
}

export const SearchInput = (props: IProps) =>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" onChange={props.handleSearchTyping} />;
```

---

Needed to use the `event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>` type.